# What purpose does the the latrine "secret" in Starcraft 2 "Zero Hour" mission have?

Tags: starcraft-2

While playing the Starcraft 2 mission "Zero hour", i found a latrine at the top center of the map, in between of two Zerg bases. When i clicked it three times, it flew away and a "Secret found!" text popped up.

Does it unlock something? Or is it just an easter egg?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an easter egg. Tauren Marine!

Supposedly, if you unlock it, you can see the outhouse flying around in space during some of the cutscenes (though I can't validate that, as I have yet to see it)

Comment: +1 After some googling i found this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3H4Yo_81G0

Comment: Here's another one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIVFlpeUFBs

Comment: Actually the latrine flies around even if you don't unlock the secret.

Answer (score 1):

Playing the "Maw of the void" level, you can watch out in space the occasional outhouse rocketing through. I usually saw this flying on the bottom of the map. Please note this is a background graphic, and can only be seen while looking into the open space places of the map. it will not appear over the platform your units are based on.